# What would be a good project to learn node.js

Tags: node.js

Everyone is talking about **NodeJS** so I though I'll look into it by creating a usefull project but I cant really think of something usefull to build on NodeJS tha fully demonstrates it's capabilities.

does any of you have a good idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's web-based apps you're interested in creating, and if you don't mind following a tutorial, then I'll recommend DailyJS's tutorial series on building a web-based, Notepad-like application from start to finish on Node: http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa.

It covers all the basics, including databases, middleware, templates and testing.

Comment: One problem I see with that series for someone, like the OP, who wants to learn Node is that they're using an existing framework, instead of developing their own. It's disappointing to see this trend developing in the Node world because Node IMO is about making these low-level tools available to the developer. It actually does the developer a disservice, because most of the time is spent learning someone else's DSL instead of the important concepts underlying the base technology.

Comment: @TK-421, I agree with you that this may not suit the OP at all, and that building a low-level library is a much better exercise for understanding what node is *really* about. But I'll leave my answer there as it depends on what you're really interested in doing. If it is to see how building web apps on Node is different to that on other technologies then building a framework isn't all that useful.

Comment: Oh, that was less about your answer and more about getting up on my soapbox and presenting the contrarian's viewpoint. ;)

Comment: And I agree that the answer depends on the OP's goals. :)

Comment: thanks for everyone comments but I'll go with this since it covers a lot of aspects.

Comment: Your link didn't seem to be right. Is this what you meant? http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/

Comment: @Box9 theres a startup called Box8 in India. Lol . On a serious note the site in the answer is Down . http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/ is up

Answer (score 5):

Build a web framework, like everybody else. ;)

But seriously, this can expose you to network programming, file i/o, and HTTP at a level that isn't typically reached when using someone else's framework (hands-on is much better than reading somebody else's code).

With Node it may no longer be "Build a blog," but rather "Build a framework that builds a blog."

Answer (score 2):

Just any website should do. You could for example do a blog involving NodeJS and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

> I cant really think of something usefull to build on NodeJS tha fully demonstrates it's capabilities.

Node.js can be probably hardly used to build single useful project or module which demonstrates all of it's capabilities because there are many areas which it can be applied to. I would say you should pick the area which interests you the most so that you won't lose your enthusiasm and eventually you can become an expert in that particular area.